# Visualforce page does not have valid controller for use with action

Tags: lightning, action, unmanaged-package

I am doing unmanaged package containing App within it.After I press upload button I get the below error as "Visualforce page does not have valid controller for use with action" [image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the controller included?

Comment: yes , I have included standardcontroller and extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the Visualforce page uses a custom controller, you need to include that Apex Class as well.
You can check the first line of the VF page.  If the `<apex:page>` tag contains "controller=" and/or "extensions=" then you need to include the class(es) named there.

Comment: hi @Brian Oconnell   I have include standardcontroller and extensions also. but still ocurring same  error.